# cross-TU optimization for a static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, static-libraries, lto

Link-time optimizations are usually implemented by putting some IR into the object files instead of actual machine code. Thus when dealing with static libraries it's just a collection of such IR files and LTO has to be done every single time the code using it is changed.
If you build a shared library instead LTO is only done once and the code inside the dll is fully optimized.

Is it also possible to have some optimizations across translation units when dealing with static libraries? I know it won't be the same as you can't make any whole-program assumptions but shouldn't it be possible to do some basic things like inlining setters/getters that aren't defined in the header?

Comment: I guess the only thing that comes close to this is unity builds. But those may lead to more code being pulled in from the lib.